# How to import files for when making a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, import, axios

I am currently building a chrome extension and trying to use axios to make request to my backend. But I keep getting errors when importing axios in my javascript file. Dose anyone know how to properly require this in?

I already tried:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
```

And I've also tried the old way with

```js
const axios = require ('axios')
```

Comment: A browser isn't node.js so to use import you need to declare those scripts in your HTML file with type=”module”. To use require you need to load that function first, as it's not built-in. It's also possible you simply need to build your scripts with webpack ok or similar tool to produce a browser-compatible bundle.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this approach?

In your manifest file, you will add the file inside the content_scripts:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
    "js": ["file.js", "content.js"]
}],
```

Then try to create this method that will read script/library you want to use:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:
    "document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'https://example.com/script.js';"
});
```

However it is not so easy, because the content script has an access only to the DOM of the current page. It can't run global functions or use global objects.